# Не доходит почта отправленная с помощью PHP

Tags: php, email, gmail

Здравствуйте. Привязал почту домена к gmail следуя [этой](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=ru&answer=33352) инструкции.
Если на почту писать с помощью почтовика (с другого gmail аккаунта, или с mail.ru и т.д.)
То на gmail почта доходит нормально. А вот если отправлять с помощью функции mail() на PHP, то письмо на gmail не попадает, а попадает на внутреннюю почту домена на хостинге.

MX записи установил следую инструкции. Вот они:

```
Hostname    Type    Priority    Value

domain.ru    MX  10  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

domain.ru    MX  20  ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM    
domain.ru    MX  30  ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM    
domain.ru    MX  40  ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM  
domain.ru    MX  50  ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM  
domain.ru    MX  60  ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.COM  
domain.ru    MX  70  ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Потому что когда вы отправляете письмо на ваш сайт, почтовик смотрит на записи домена, в том числе и mx, и по ним уже определяет, куда дальше идет письмо. Вам же нужно воспользоваться протоколом SMTP чтобы вы смогли отправлять письма от аккаунта gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю у вас postfix настроен на то чтобы локальная почта не шла в мир. Вам нужно в руткоде вопрос задать.